# AttributeError when trying to call tkinter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn how to use tkinter to create a GUI with python. I just installed Visual Studio Code as I wanted to try a new IDE, but I get the following error when trying to run my code:

AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'

The code in question is just:

```
import tkinter as tk

tk.Tk()
```

I have tried to run the same code in IDLE and PyCharm, where it works fine. I can also without problems write the same code in the python shell from within VSC. I have tried to import other modules into VSC and that code runs just fine when I call the modules. Any suggestions?

Comment: the tkinter API has changed a bit for Python 2 and Python 3. Look in the tkinter source what to use.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have some `tkinter.py` file created in the current directory and because of the higher precedence that module/file is imported when you call `import tkinter as tk`.

Just rename that `tkinter.py` file to something else.

Comment: That did indeed solve my problem. Thank you so much!